# document.getElementById("id").valid not working in higher versions of firefox

Tags: firefox-addon, firebreath

I am working on a firefox plugin that uses firebreath framework. The plugin checks whether the firebreath dll is registered using the following code.

```
if(document.getElementByID("dllID").valid)
{
alert("Dll registered");
}
else
{
alert("Condition failed");
}
```

The code works fine for firefox upto version 28.

For higher versions the condition always fails. Can anyone help me in this??

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of the `valid` attribute. What are you trying to accomplish exactly? If it is for form validation, you probably need to deal with `validation` objects https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation#The_HTML5_constraint_validation_API

```
if (document.getElementbyID("dllID").validity.valid){
    ...
} else {
    ....
}
```

Whats more, is this api [seems to be present in FF29+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) so it probably deprecated the plain `valid` attribute you are used to

Answer (score 0):

Try `.hasAttribute`, `.getAttribute`, and `.setAttribute`

```
document.getElementByID("dllID").hasAttribute('valid')
```

Without these, is usually for XBL properties but things like `id` work too.